# Ошибка при сортировке бинарными вставками "faulted with message 'access violation' "

Tags: delphi

Ошибка или в сортировках, или не так вызываю процедуру, я уже запуталась.

```
   procedure BiSortInteger(var Arr:tmyarr1);
    var
    i,j,s,x,l,n,r:integer;
    begin
      for i:=2 to n do
        begin
        x:=arr[i];
        l:=1; r:=i-1;
        repeat
           s:=(l+r) div 2;
           if arr[s]<x then l:=s+1
           else r:=s-1;
           until l>r;
              for j:=i-1 downto l do arr[j+1]:=arr[j];
              arr[l]:=x;
          end;
    end;

    procedure BiSortReal(var Arr:Tmyarr2);
    var
    i,j,s,l,r,n:integer;
    x:real;
    begin
    for i:=2 to n do
      begin
      x:=arr[i];
      l:=1; r:=i-1;
        repeat
          s:=(l+r) div 2;
          if arr[s]<x then l:=s+1
          else r:=s-1;
          until l>r;
            for j:=i-1 downto l do arr[j+1]:=arr[j];
            arr[l]:=x;
          end;
    end;
```

Comment: @hhhhhh, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться. Пожалуйста, отформатируйте ваш код.

Comment: @hhhhhh: а в какой строке падает?

Comment: @VladD x:=arr[i];

Comment: @kot-da-vinci n - кол-во элементов в массиве

Comment: Что-то я не заметил где в Вашем коде переменной `n` присваивается значение количества элементов в массиве? Компилятор должен сам догадаться, что `n` нужно проинициализировать количеством значений в массиве? Падает в `x:=arr[i]` тогда, когда `i` выходит за пределы массива.

Comment: И еще, если цикл по `i` начинается с 2, то, похоже, что нулевой элемент массива вообще не будет участвовать в сортировке. Т.е. если в массиве будет всего 2 элемента (0-ой и 1-ый), то никакой сортировки вообще не будет.

Comment: @hhhhhh: А чему равно `i` в этой точке? А `n`? Могу поспорить, их значения не такие, как вы ожидаете. Умеете пользоваться отладчиком, надеюсь?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в сортировках с первой строки:

```
for i:=2 to n do
```

Чему у Вас равно `n` в этой строке в первой и второй сортировке?

Отформатируйте циклы отступами, у Вас каша, а не код.

Для начала должно быть так:

```
for i:=2 to Length(Arr) - 1 do
```